# How can Clean Architecture's interface adapters adapt interfaces if they cannot know the details of the infrastructure they are adapting?

Tags: clean-architecture

From what I've understood from Clean Architecture, every layer can directly depend only on internal layers and, related to external layers, only abstractions are allowed to be set as a dependency, with DIP. Following this rule, the Adapters layer is allowed to directly depend on the Application layer and it only can have the Infrastructure layer as a dependency through abstractions. In my conception, that does not make any sense because, in order for an adapter to be able to perform translation between interfaces, it must know in detail which interfaces it is adapting - not knowing details of one side, abstractions on the other side. I've searched for that and didn't find convincing answers.

Comment: Do you mean the [*Framework & Drivers*](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) layer when you are talking about the *Infrastructure layer*?

Comment: Yes, I mean the external layer

Answer (score 5):

This question is probably one of the most controversial in Clean Architecture and (as to my understanding) the one where Hexagonal Architecture and Clean Architecture differ the most.

The general concept in Clean Architecture is: the inner layer provides an interface which is implemented by the outer layer. This approach can be followed by the adapters layer as well.

Imagine you want to implement a repository pattern which accesses an SQL database. Then, in the adapters layer you would implement an interface from the use cases layer which is most convenient for the use cases. This interface would probably have APIs rather specific to the needs of the use cases like "GetAllCustomersWithOpenOrders" or "GetOrderHistoryOfCustomer". Now in order to implement these APIs the adapter would need access to the SQL database For that it would again define an interface which is convenient for the adapter, so it would probably define generic CRUD Apis to pass some SQL as string. This interface would then be implemented in the "frameworks and drivers" layer by a class which would then know how to access the database (it would have the connection string and may depend on a vendor specific DB access library).

With this approach the dependency rule of the Clean Architecture is maintained but it would probably raise 2 questions:

1. Isn't the adapter still "technology dependent" if it builds up SQL strings? Yes it is, but the adapter not necessarily needs to be technology independent, if it is independent from specific frameworks, vendors or external services. We could easily add another adapter which "creates a bridge" between the interface defined in the use cases layer and a document database.
2. What is the value of such an adapter if we need still one more interface and one more implementation in the frameworks layer? The answer probably heavily depends on the "conceptual difference" between those two interfaces. In the example above the adapter would still contain all the knowledge about the DB schema, how to do the joins and so how to build complex queries. The implementation in the frameworks layer would be very small as it would probably just pass on the SQL query through the vendor specific library to the proper DB instance. Replacing on DB vendor by another would be possible with minimal impact to your application. In other cases the ration might be the other way round and the adapter might only be a "data conversion" layer.

Personally I still didn't found a "silver bullet" to this question so I try to make a "pragmatic" decision, case by case, as I tried to summarize in my blog post: http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Frameworks/

**Update 2022-11-08**
Created a YouTube video which discusses this topic in further depth: [Repository Pattern: CORRECT vs. pragmatic? | Clean Architecture](https://youtu.be/pfhDO_hZixw)

Comment: From what I understood on your answer, the adapters layer should have a "brief" notion of which technology it is handling like protocols and paradigms such as HTTP and SQL while still remaining independent on external vendors like express for web http server and postgresql for SQL database. I wonder if it wouldn't be easier if the adapters knew infrastructure in detail and directly connects its APIs with usecases abstractions through dependency injection, like, let's say, postgresqlAdapter being an object which calls implemented usecases.

Comment: Right, this is how I understood Uncle Bob. And I agree, having the direct dependency from adapter to e.g. DB is "easier" in the sense of "less code to write" and maybe even in the sense of "easier to understand". Question is probably: which qualities (e.g. portability, changeability) are more important for you in the long run. Replacing one specific external service, technology or vender is certainly easier the less code you have which directly depends on it. And personally I think this decision has to be taken for each project individually; see my blog post, I often go the "Pragmatic way" ;-)

Comment: Just read your amazing article, thnaks for the recommendation. You showed 3 approaches: The ideal one, which hide interface adapters under an interface, thus maintaining the dependency rule; The ignored adapters one, which you directly implements interactors on the frameworks layer and the pragmatic one, in which you break the dependency rule on the adapters circle, making adapters attached to chosen libraries. I'm considering moving on with one of these two last approaches, because I can't imagine a logic that fits into adapters without using specific libraries APis.

Comment: Even in your blog post, the class inside the interface adapters layer seems to just pass the "GetWorkItems()" method, implemented by the frameworks layer, into the usecases, without applying any adapter-specific logic. Can you provide an example where a specific logic fits only into the adapters circle, without depending on external elements?

Comment: I don't have a code example yet - but already planning a YouTube video as this is quite a tricky aspect of Clean Architecture ;-) - but imagine the example i gave in the answer above: the adapter uses SQL "standard" to build a complex query and deliver complex data structure to the use cases layer while the frameworks layer just provides CRUD Apis taking some SQL string. Or maybe the frameworks layer returns some other "quasi standard" like Json and the adapter converts it into something convenient for the use cases.

Comment: It feels like your example is more the exception than the rule and that most of the time the adapters in the adapters layer will just be wrappers around adapters in the infrastructure layer. Still in most articles about clean architecture they say that you are free to have more than the four layers. They never talk about the option to remove the adapters layer.